# why no of request is different from used limit in google place api

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have made request to google place  API  no of request is near about 1500-1600 but in used quota limit showing 15800 . I have verified my account.

request:

```
$baseurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json";
```

why ?

[image]

Comment: How are you making the request?

Comment: can any one say why question is downmark ?

Comment: Please provide the code for the request.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kVRUqPTd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a textSearch.  Text Search has a 10 times multiplier.  [From the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests):

> The Google Places search services share the same usage limits. However, **the Text Search service is subject to a 10-times multiplier**. That is, each Text Search request that you make will count as 10 requests against your quota. If you've purchased the Google Places API as part of your Google Maps API for Work contract, the multiplier may be different. Please refer to the Google Maps API for Work documentation for details.