# Google Places API Web Service WRONG quotas calculate

Tags: web-services, google-maps, google-places-api

Hello guys can you explain me, why it happened...

[I sent 142 requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq97r.jpg)

[But when I open Quotas panel, I see that i use 970 requests from 1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHDKS.jpg)

[If quotas == 1000 I will get ERROR like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpBJI.jpg)

Don't understand why 142 requests used 970 quotas??

Comment: What are the requests you sent?

Comment: @geocodezip,  I used requests like :
`var request = {
        location: pyrmont,
        radius: '50000',
        query: place_type
    };
service.textSearch(request, callback);
`
and

 `service.getDetails()`

In general I sent 142 Requests

Comment: A textSearch counts as 10 requests, see the documentation

Comment: duplicate of [why no of request is different from used limit in google place api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984774/why-no-of-request-is-different-from-used-limit-in-google-place-api)

Comment: @geocodezip Got it, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text Search has a 10 times multiplier.  [From the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests):

> The Google Places search services share the same usage limits. However, **the Text Search service is subject to a 10-times multiplier**. That is, each Text Search request that you make will count as 10 requests against your quota. If you've purchased the Google Places API as part of your Google Maps API for Work contract, the multiplier may be different. Please refer to the Google Maps API for Work documentation for details.